# Unable to respond to more than one click on an interactive message

Tags: laravel, bots, slack

I want to be able to retrieve responses from:
a) as many people on the channel
b) identify the user who chose what option

For some reason, after the first person has clicked, thereafter any response just goes to the fallback.

How would I achieve this? and this is my file

This is my controller page:-

```
namespace App\Conversations;
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Conversations\ExampleConversation;
use App\Conversations\MenuConversation;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Incoming\Answer;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Outgoing\Actions\Button;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Outgoing\Question;
use BotMan\Drivers\Slack\Extensions\Menu;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class BotSlackController extends Controller
{


    public function getSlackUsers()
    {
        $guzzle = \App::make(Client::class);

        $user_data = [];
        $slack_token = "xoxb-2893074844-363165652051-cCiOK0lMGHf5e72QF6s04Nbl";
        $user_list_url = "https://slack.com/api/users.list?token=$slack_token&pretty=1";

        $user_list = $guzzle->request('GET', $user_list_url)->getBody()->getContents();

        $user_list = json_decode($user_list);
        if (!empty($user_list->members)) {
            foreach ($user_list->members as $user_info) {
                if ($user_info->deleted == true) {
                    continue;
                }
                $user_data[] = ['id' => $user_info->id, 'name' => $user_info->real_name];
            }
        }
        return $user_data;
    }

    public function sendMessageView()
    {
        $slack_users = $this->getSlackUsers();
        return view('slackMessage', ['slack_users' => $slack_users]);
    }

    public function sendControllerBot(Request $request) {
        /*$data = \App::make(ExampleConversation::class);
        $data->sendBot($request);*/

        $botman = app('botman');
        $user_id = $request['slackUserId'];
        $user_msg = $request['slackMessage'];

        $botman->startConversation(new MenuConversation(),$user_id,\BotMan\Drivers\Slack\SlackDriver::class);

        //$botman->listen();
    }


}
```

This is my MenuConversation file:-

```
<?php

namespace App\Conversations;

use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Incoming\Answer;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Outgoing\Question;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Outgoing\Actions\Button;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Conversations\Conversation;

class MenuConversation extends Conversation
{


 public function askBtn()
    {
        $question = Question::create("Hello, How are you?")
            ->fallback('Unable to create a new database')
            ->callbackId('ask_btn')
            ->addButtons([
                Button::create('I am fine')->value('fine'),
                Button::create('Not good')->value('no_good'),
                Button::create('Do not disturb')->value('wont_disturb')
            ]);


        return $this->ask($question, function (Answer $answer) {
            if ($answer->isInteractiveMessageReply()) {
                $result = $answer->getValue();
//Will actually store it in a DB and yet to figure how to retrieve the Slack User that selected the option
            /\* $this->say("Hello I got your response. Response: ".$result); \*/
                $this->bot->reply("Hello I got your response. Response: ".$result);
            }

        });

    }

       public function run()
    {
        $this->askBtn();
    }
}
```

First time when I click any button I get the value of the button I clicked but immediate after second click it goes to my fallback function which I created in `botman.php`.

Please anyone help me out in this.

1. How I can get multi-response(or multi time click response)
2. If I send a message in public channel instead of Particular user, How I can fetch the user Id who clicked the button.

Comment: May I get any response? Is there anything wrong in my code? Has no one faced this kind of situation yet?

Comment: Did you figure this out yet?